# Return HTTP Status BAD_REQUEST using a custom resolver in Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I am developing a REST API using **Spring Boot 1.5.15**. I have implemented a customer `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to map an HTTP header. In details, I assign the value of the HTTP header `Some-Header`, removing the prefix "XXX ".

First of all, I defined a custom annotation.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface SomeHeader {
}
```

Then, I implemented a custom resolver.

```
public class SomeHeaderArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterAnnotation(SomeHeader.class) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
                                  ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                  NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                                  WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) webRequest.getNativeRequest();
        final String headerValue = request.getHeader("Some-Header");

        return headerValue.replace("XXX ", "");
    }
}
```

And finally, I made Spring aware of the resolver in a configuration class.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new SomeHeaderArgumentResolver());
    }
}
```

Now, I can use the following mapping in any controller I need.

```
@PostMapping("/some/paath")
public void someMethod(@SomeHeader String someHeaderValue) {
   // Method body...
}
```

However, `Some-Header` information is mandatory for me. I want that if it is not present, Spring returns a 400 Bad Request response to the caller. It is the same behaviour I can obtain using the `@RequestHeader("Some-Header")` annotation.

Can I replicate the same behaviour? Possibly, I don't want to use a dedicated *controller advice*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion given by @madhu-bhat, I understand which is the correct class to extend to let Spring doing the magic.

The class `RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver`, used by Spring to resolve HTTP headers values inside Java object, extends the abstract class `AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver`. This class let you specify if the header value has some default value, using the `createNamedValueInfo` method.

So, it follows the code.

```
public class SomeHeaderArgumentResolver extends AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver {
    @Override
    protected NamedValueInfo createNamedValueInfo(MethodParameter parameter) {
        // The second parameter specifies if the value is required, 
        // and the third if there is some default value.
        return new NamedValueInfo("", true, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object resolveName(String name, 
                                 MethodParameter parameter, 
                                 NativeWebRequest request) {
        final String headerValue = request.getHeader("Some-Value");
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(headerValue)) {
            // Returning null tells Spring that there is no value for the parameter
            return null;
        }
        return headerValue.replace("XXX ", "");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return (parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(SomeHeader.class) &&
                !Map.class.isAssignableFrom(
                    parameter.nestedIfOptional().getNestedParameterType()));
    }
}
```

The only thing I don't like is that I am using structures developed to handle *named values*, but I don't have a *named value*.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But does it help you send 400 if the header value is not present as you asked in your question?

Comment: Yep, if the `resolveName` method returns the value `null`, Spring returns a 400 BAD REQUEST HTTP response.

Comment: Even when you return null value, internally it throws ServletRequestBindingException itself. So the 500 that you saw earlier might be due to some other reason.

Answer (score 2):

If you see the implementation of `RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver` which is used for `@RequestHeader`, you'll see an overridden implementation of `handleMissingValue` method of `AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver` abstract class as below:

```
@Override
protected void handleMissingValue(String name, MethodParameter parameter) throws ServletRequestBindingException {
        throw new ServletRequestBindingException("Missing request header '" + name +
                "' for method parameter of type " + parameter.getNestedParameterType().getSimpleName());
}
```

This `handleMissingValue` method is used in the `resolveArgument` method of `AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver`, which `RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver` extends, based on some conditions. So when the header is absent and the `ServletRequestBindingException` is thrown, Spring's `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` would handle that and send a **400** response.

So that is how the validation works in case of `@RequestHeader`. So you can implement something similar in the `resolveArgument` method of your `SomeHeaderArgumentResolver` class as below:

```
public class SomeHeaderArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterAnnotation(SomeHeader.class) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
                                  ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                  NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                                  WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) webRequest.getNativeRequest();
        final String headerValue = request.getHeader("Some-Header");
        if(headerValue != null){
           return headerValue.replace("XXX ", "");
        } else {
           //handle scenario if header absent with ServletRequestBindingException
        }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work :( It returns a 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.

Comment: I found how to resolve my problem. Please, try to have a look.

Comment: @riccardo.cardin but this would solve your problem too without the need for overriding anything else right?

Comment: @riccardo.cardin please consider upvoting if my answer helped.

Comment: To use your answer, I also need to register the `DispatcherServlet` and to throw an exception actively. Merely changing the supertype of my resolver, I don't need to do anything else.

Comment: @riccardo.cardin actually you don't have to register dispatcherservlet since it is registered by default. The reason why you saw 500 would probably because you might have handled Exception class in your exception handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your own exceptions for any cases and set ExceptionHandler in controller to return correct http-status.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler({SameHeaderException.class})
public Object onSameHeaderException(SameHeaderException e) {
    return ImmutableMap.of("reason", e.getMessage());
}
```

So you can throw this exception if header is absent:

```
if (someHeaderValue == null) { throw new SameHeaderException(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a Spring boot 2.7.17 example based on the ideas here.
The example uses a **@RequestHeaderEmail** custom parameter anotation. When this annotation appears, it puts the "X-EMAIL" request header's value in it.
If there is no such header or it is null or empty, the REST method will return with Bad Request.

Usage:

```
@RestController
public class RqController {
   @GetMapping
   String displayEmailHeader(@RequestHeaderEmail String email) {
     return email;
   }
}
```

Annotation:

```
   @Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   @Documented
   public @interface RequestHeaderEmail {}
```

Resolver:

```
public class RequestHeaderEmailResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return String.class.equals(parameter.getParameter().getType()) && parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(RequestHeaderEmail.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        String email = webRequest.getHeader("X-EMAIL");
        if (email == null || email.isEmpty()) throw new ServletRequestBindingException("X-EMAIL header should not be null or empty");

        return email;
    }
}
```

Set up:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AnnotationConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new RequestHeaderEmailResolver());
    }

}
```

Here is a github repo with unit tests:
https://github.com/peterborkuti/request_param_custom_annotation/tree/main